# Did the JSSOR option $AutoPlayInterval change to $Idle in 28.0.0?

Tags: jssor

I upgraded from jssor 27.5.0 to 28.8.0, and now it seems like $AutoPlayInterval no longer works. In the API, I see that there is an option $Idle that sounds similar.  Did something change unannounced?

Comment: Yes, $AutoPlayInterval has been changed to $Idle.

Comment: https://www.jssor.com/development/api-options.html